# how to show $\{ X_t \}$ in the title of a plot of R

Tags: r, plotmath

How to show $\{ X_t \}$ of Latex in the title of a plot of R?

For example

```
 plot(slot(x,"GRID"),slot(x,"PATH"),type="l", xlab="Time t",ylab="X",
 main=paste("Simulation of \{X_t\}"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... interesting Q. May I add to this: Is there a ggplot2 way to do it?

Comment: @ran2: You do it the same way, they all us plotmath. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you will provide meaningful arguments for the slot expressions, then I think there is a reasonable chance that this is what you want:

```
plot(1:10,1:10,type="l", xlab="Time t",ylab="X",
      main=expression("Simulation of {"*X[t]*"}"))
```

This is a plotmath expression that presents "t" as a subscript of "X" and that expression is enclosed in curley braces. If I have misread your request, then note that the "*" character is a separator in the plotmath syntax and the braces are simply characters than can be deleted. (The LaTeX expressions don't make a lot of sense to those of us who just use the plotmath syntax, so describing what you want in prose or mathematical jargon would work better for any clarifications.)

Answer (score 6):

To have R emulate LaTeX typesetting, see the examples and methods described in `?plotmath`.

To actually have LaTeX typeset your plot text, use the `tikz()` graphics device  provided by the `tikzDevice` package.

Comment: Thanks!What are the strength and weakness for each of these two methods?

Comment: The strength of using the tikzDevice LaTeX handles the typesetting for ALL of the text in your paper, figures included.  This means you can typeset arcane equations and your figure font will seamlessly match the rest of your paper---even if you happen to be using Klingon.  The advantage of using R's built-in PDF is that it does not depend on a LaTeX compiler to be present and you do not have to contend with the world of LaTeX error messages in addition to the world of R error messages.

Answer (score 4):

The `group()` plotmath function can be used to formalise DWin's answer. This solution has the advantage (IMHO) of not using strings as part of the expression. Instead we use the `~` operator to add spacing (whitespace is ignored).

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type = "l", xlab = "Time t", ylab = "X",
     main=expression(Simulation ~ of ~ group("{", X[t], "}")))
```

The `bgroup()` plotmath function provides scalable delimiters but is used in the same manner as the example code above.

**Edit** (In response to ran2's comment):
The same approaches can be used in ggplot and lattice, using the power of plotmath, just as with base graphics. E.g.

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 1:10)
qplot(A, B, data = df,
      main = expression(Simulation ~ of ~ group("{", X[t], "}")))
```